# Converts Unicode Entities to Unicode Text

Tags: python, unicode

Can Python convert Unicode Entities to Unicode? 
`ex) \u0639\u0631\u0628\u0649 to عربى`

I want the exact same thing which can be done [in this website](http://unicode.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php)

This will help me to parse JSON unicode entities to generate valid URL

`ex) 'S\\u00f8ren Kierkegaard'  ->  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Søren_Kierkegaard`

FYI, if you use Wikipedia API, you will meet many objects like `'\\u00f8'` [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Søren_Kierkegaard&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=S%C3%B8ren_Kierkegaard&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json)

Comment: when I see such unicode problems I'm really fearing and trembling :)

Comment: I have struggled with this 'conceptually simple' stuff with several hours. I feel dizzy now.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What type of string do you have? Does it have to use the `%uxxxx` pattern? You know how to represent things using Python's style, can't you just convert this?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the `json` module to parse the entities?  `json.loads('{"value": ["\\u0639\\u0631\\u0628\\u0649"]}')` => `{'value': ['عربى']}`

Comment: @Mark Tolonen Maybe because of the programming context in my code? I had to find the entities using 'findall'.     

```wikisource = wikiresponse.read()
 linkstuple = re.findall('\*\s*(St.)?\s*\[\[([^\]|]*)(?=.*\]\])', wikisource, re.UNICODE)```
If I parse wikisource using `json` module, then I could't use .findall method anymore.. it requires string rather than dict type.

So I tried alternate approach, which is, after getting the entities by regular expression, then decode the entities.

Answer (score 4):

Python supports an encoding called `unicode-escape` that will help here:

```
>>> br'\u0639\u0631\u0628\u0649'.decode('unicode-escape')
'عربى'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = u'\u0639\u0631\u0628\u0649'
>>> print a
عربى
>>>
```